# Is my custom twig form error free and secure?

Tags: templates, symfony, twig

Basically I am displaying a template that is showcasing some data read from the database. The user is allowed to check the table row and click "remove" to delete those from the database. In order to do that I wrote a custom form around a table. Is this form valid? Am I missing anything? I am only asking because I kind of did this on my own and am not sure if I am making any mistakes.

Thanks

```
<form action="{{ path('main_referral_capture_manage_physicians') }}" method="post">           
  <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="20">Select</th>
      <th width="200">Referring Physician</th>
      <th width="150">NPI Number</th>
      <th width="150">Practice</th>
      <th width="150">Location</th>
      <th width="150">Phone</th>
      <th width="150">Fax</th>
      <th width="150">Email Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      {% for physician in physicians %}
    <tr>
      <td><input name="chkphysician[]" type="checkbox" value="{{physician.id}}" /></td>
      <td>{{ physician.physicianFirstName }} {{ physician.physicianLastName }}</td>
      <td>{{ physician.physicianNpi }}</td>
      <td>{{ physician.physicianPracticeName }}</td>
      <td>{{ physician.physicianLocationName }}</td>
      <td>{{ physician.physicianPhone }}</td>
      <td>{{ physician.physicianFax }}</td>
      <td>{{ physician.physicianEmail }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Remove" />          
</form>
```

Comment: From an OO perspective, I see a bit of redundancy in your naming. You already know your on the physician object, so why prepend your property names with physician, i.e. physicianEmail, physicianNpi, etc?

Comment: good point. I will fix that.

Comment: You are going to make processing your data more difficult than it needs to be by way of how your naming your checkbox. I would just call it "physicianIds", or simply "ids". Then in your controller, the Request will contain an array of ids the user wants to delete (if 1 or more checkboxes are checked).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no inherent issues with your twig form. To validate your twig forms, you can run the lint command:

```
php app/console twig:lint @SomeBundleName
```